# how to assign the property to checkbox

Tags: excel, vba

hi i have a checkbox and code if i run it shows error. please rectify this error.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    With Sheets("bom")
        If .CheckBox1.Value = True Then
            .Range("show_all_level") = "Yes"
        Else
            .Range("show_all_level") = "No"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

type of error:

[image]

Comment: You probably don't have a defined range called "show_all_level" . Check in your Formula tab>Name Manager and see if  you have a defined range called "show_all_level" ?

Comment: Is the defined named range **show_all_level** on the same worksheet as the checkbox? i.e. Worksheets("bom")

Comment: More importantly, is the CheckBox1 on Sheet bom?

Comment: Yes, it is in Sheet("bom")

Comment: Which line is highlighted when the error occurs?

Comment: 4th line @ Tim Williams

Comment: Try this in the Immediate pane: `? Sheets("bom").Range("show_all_level").Address()` what happens when you press Enter ?

Comment: @DINESHKUMAR PALANISAMY  have you read my answer and code below ? is it working for you now as you intended ?

Comment: Ya it works thanks @ Shai Rado sorry for late response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below, it should handle different scenarios you might have with your "show_all_level" `Name Range`.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

Dim Nm          As Name
Dim NmExist     As Boolean
Dim NameRng     As Range

' loop through all Name Ranges in ThisWorkbook
For Each Nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
    If Nm.Parent.Name Like "bom" Then '<-- check if name range parent (Sheet.Name) is "bom"
        MsgBox Nm.Name & " Name Range exists is sheet " & Chr(34) & Nm.Parent.Name & Chr(34)
        NmExist = True ' raise the flag >> Name exist in "bom" sheet
        Set NameRng = Nm.RefersToRange ' set the Range to the Name Range
        Exit For
    ElseIf Nm.Parent.CodeName Like "ThisWorkbook" Then '<-- check if name scope is "ThisWorkbook"
        MsgBox Nm.Name & " Name Range exists as WorkBook scope"
        NmExist = True ' raise the flag >> Name exist in Workbook scope
        Set NameRng = Nm.RefersToRange ' set the Range to the Name Range
        Exit For
    End If
Next Nm

' verify that "show_all_level" name exist in "bom" sheet (or Workbook scope)
If Not NmExist Then
    MsgBox Chr(34) & "show_all_level" & Chr(34) & "Name Range, doesn't exist in the desired sheet", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

With Sheets("bom")
    If .CheckBox1.Value = True Then
        NameRng.Value = "Yes"
    Else
        NameRng.Value = "No"
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @DINESHKUMARPALANISAMY see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289619

Comment: @0m3r thanks for this link ;) I have needed it in the past so many times ;)